# Production of town gas

Tags: carbon-dioxide, industrial-chemistry

Town gas contains quite a lot of chemicals.

Based on my research, the order of abundance of its constitutes is hydrogen, carbon monoxide, nitrogen, carbon dioxide, gaseous naphtha and oxygen, if arranged in descending order).

I do not understand why the abundance of carbon monoxide is greater than that of carbon dioxide since carbon monoxide can be converted into carbon dioxide due to the reaction $\ce{2CO + O2 -> 2CO2}$. So, in my opinion, the abundance of carbon dioxide will certainly be greater.

I propose several possibilities:

1. The problem boils down to inaccurate or incorrect data of my research
2. The reaction $\ce{2CO + O2 -> 2CO2}$ is hard to take place

Are there any other possibilities, or what should be an answer to my question?

Comment: The border between _"there is"_ and _"there isn't"_ is not where you think it is. **There isn't** any significant amount of oxygen there, hence CO stays CO.

Comment: For future reference:  for the body of questions, answers, and comments, chemistry.se offers to use [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) as a comfortable method to add chemical equations.

Comment: Reactions like the oxidation of CO to CO2 don't just happen. The production process of Town gas is  *designed* to minimise the proportion of CO2 and to maximise the proportion of CO (CO2 is a useless product, CO is a useful fuel). H2 and CO are the major useful components of the gas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from carbon (which coal is not), the two most common oxidations yield carbon monoxide (incomplete combustion, $\ce{2C + O2 -> 2CO}$), or carbon dioxide (complete combustion, $\ce{C + O2 -> CO2}$).  However, there equally is a temperature dependent chemical endothermic equilibrium between carbon, carbon monoxide, and carbon dioxide ($\ce{C + CO2 <=> 2CO}$) equally known as [Boudouard reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boudouard_reaction) which is of significance e.g., in blast furnaces to generate iron:

[image]

(image credit to [openstax.org](https://openstax.org/books/chemistry/pages/19-1-occurrence-preparation-and-properties-of-transition-metals-and-their-compounds))

A high concentration of $\ce{CO2}$ in town gas is not desirable because contrasting to $\ce{CO}$ it does not oxidize further (which eventually is the source of heat why town gas principally is/was used for).  Instead (similar to nitrogen), $\ce{CO2}$ picks up heat which otherwise would be available for a combustion of pure $\ce{CO}$ with pure $\ce{O2}$, and dilutes the reagents; both lower the maximal temperature of the flame.  Hence the generation of town gas runs within reaction parameters (e.g., temperature, pressure, residential time of the reagents in the reactor) where the yield of carbon monoxide is maximized.

While it is possible to burn pure $\ce{CO}$ with pure $\ce{O2}$, the required purification of town gas to remove nitrogen; carbon dioxide, and other gases *at scale (and flux) of consumption by cities* would require large additional technical installations.  There is too little (economical) incentive to offset these investments.